# Issues with SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib library

Tags: ssh

Recently I've discovered, that my SSH client is having connection troubles towards servers using `SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib` SSH library. I've invested quite some time into searching for any information about this type of library or source codes, or a way to install this SSH library to my test server to try to reproduce and possibly also solve this issue by myself, but I haven't found anything besides few forum topics mentioning some unrelated troubles with this library.

Does anyone know something about `SSH-2.0-9.99 sshlib 8.1.0.0`? Is this some proprietary implementation of SSH? Could you please point me somewhere to find a little bit more details about that? I would also greatly appreciate any information about what kind of servers/operation systems are actually using this library (I mean - if it comes packed with them just like OpenSSH does in many cases). I'm quite desperate at this point.

Comment: Well, what kind of servers are you connecting to? Are they standalone computers, routers, PLCs, toasters?

Comment: Maybe you should be asking about those connection troubles instead. As is, the question is basically off-topic. We don’t do research.

Comment: @user1686 yeah, standalone computers, it might be coincidence, but the only thing, that they have in common is this SSH library in use.
@DanielB well then, I'm afraid there's nothing to ask, it seems like servers with this library implemented does not send/handle `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_WINDOW_ADJUST` correctly, as my thread which is supposed to write data to the network is blocked because there's not enough window capacity to communicate. Might be an coincidence and these servers might just be broken, but I was really looking for a way how to reproduce this on my own test server.